# Firefox and selenium certificate

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to make a test with selenium and firefox in windows. I try to connect the script to a website that uses a SSL certificate and the browser give me a warning message that stops the test.

I've already tried this :

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
```

And also this :

```
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
```

With the same results : it doesn't work.

I'm working with the latest Firefox version and Python 2.7

Comment: Show exact warning message you get

Comment: It's aproblem with the unstrusted certificate

Comment: https://fijiaaron.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/firefox_untrusted_ssl_certificate.png this one?

Comment: I cannot acces but the error is : SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Comment: Do you actually have a certificate to this website?

Comment: you can create custom firefox profile and manually add the certificate and then use that profile for execution

Comment: How can I add the certificate in python ?

Comment: Downgrade to firefox 46

Comment: Ok, but how can I add a certificate?